# wagtail admin images and document tags

Tags: wagtail

Is there anyway how to disable images/document tags? I use lots of collections in my project and the fact that any user can see tags from any collection is unwanted, therefore I would rather not have tags at all. I can't find a way how to dissable them to t user won't see them.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around editing document/images forms using signals. If anyone is interested my solution is bellow

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_init
from wagtail.documents.models import Document
from wagtail.images.models import Image

@receiver(pre_init, sender=Document)
def document_form_hide_tags(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    '''
    hides tags from the document form
    '''
    Document.admin_form_fields = (
        'title',
        'file',
        'collection',
        # 'tags'
    )


@receiver(pre_init, sender=Image)
def image_form_hide_tags(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    '''
    hides tags from the image form
    '''
    Image.admin_form_fields = (
        'title',
        'file',
        'collection',
        # 'tags',
        'focal_point_x',
        'focal_point_y',
        'focal_point_width',
        'focal_point_height',
    )
```